# Javascript Regex: Testing string for intelligent query

Tags: javascript, regex, string, evaluation

I have a string that holds user input. This string can contain various types of data, like:

- a six digit id
- a zipcode that contains out of 4 digits and two alphanumeric characters
- a name (characters only)

As I am using this string to search through a database, the query type is determined on the type of search, which i want to handle serverside using JavaScript (yes, I am using JavaScript serverside). Searching on StackOverflow, brought me some interesting information, like the .test-method, which seems perfect for my needs. The test-method returns either true or false based on the evaluation on the string using a regex object.

I am using this page as a reference: 
http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml

So I am trying to determine the zipcode, by using the following very noobish regex.

var r = /[A-Za-z]{2,2}/

As far I can understand, this should limit the amount of occurrences of alphanumeric characters to a maximum of two. See beneath the output of my JavaScript console.

```
> var r = /[A-Za-z]{2,2}/
> var x = "2233AL"
> r.test(x)
true
> var x = "2233A"
> r.test(x)
false
> var x = "2233ALL"
> r.test(x)
true  /* i want this to be false */
>
```

A little help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/([^a-z]|^)[a-z]{2}([^a-z]|$)/i
```

part 1: ([^a-z]|^) ... no letter or start of the string

part 2: [a-z]{2} ... two letters

part 3: ([^a-z]|$) ... no letter or end of the string

/i ... case insensitive

Comment: Ah, this is more like it. Could you break down what is happening here? In my JSC it works like a bliss.

Comment: I refactored your regex to my needs thanks to your explaination: /^\d{4}[a-z]{2}$/

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var r = /[A-Za-z]{2,2}/
> ```
>
> As far I can understand, this should limit the amount of occurrences of alphanumeric characters to a maximum of two.

No, that says there should be at *least* two letters in A-Z or a-z and that they must be consecutive. There may also be more letters before or after the match. The syntax `{2,2}` is also redundant - you can use simply `{2}` which means the same thing.

This regular expression ensures a maximum of two letters in A-Z or a-z:

```
var r = /^[^A-Za-z]*([A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]*){0,2}$/;
```

This one says one or more digits followed by exactly two letters:

```
var r = /^\d+[A-Za-z]{2}$/;
```

Notice the use of anchors in both cases to ensure that there aren't any other characters before or after the match.

Comment: Wow. Does the {,2} ensure that? I want to learn the regex part too, besides copy-pasting :)

Comment: The syntax `{0,2}` means zero, one or two matches.

Comment: > var r = /^[^A-Za-z]*([A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]*){0,2}$/
> x = "2233ab"
2233ab
> r.test(x)
true
> x = "2233a"
2233a
> r.test(x)
true
> x = "2233"
2233
> r.test(x)
true <-- yikes!

Comment: @Shyam: Does *yikes* mean *Also, I forgot to mention in my question but I want it to fail to match for 0 letters. It should succeed only if there is one or two letters.* by any chance? If so, use {1,2} instead of {0,2}.

Comment: Yikes means that isn't the result i want to occur at all. Maybe from your end my question is vague, but I have supplied also the information what I am trying to achieve. Using this regex, might possible collide with an other type of search query. Don't get me wrong, I am grateful for your answer and explanation.

Comment: @Shyam: Well I'm happy you appear to have got your answer from someone else. I still am not quite sure exactly what it is you are trying to do or how the answer you accepted solves your problem, but as long as you got the answer in the end I guess it doesn't matter.